# KeyError "attr_dict" in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx, keyerror

This is my line of code. I keep getting KeyError: 'attr_dict'

```
edge_origins = [e[2]["attr_dict"]["Node1_reference"] for e in g.edges(data=True)]
```

This is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: `e[2]` has no key "attr_dict". That is all what can be said without more context (code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iterating over edges with `data=True` kwarg, the `attr_dict` will be present only if the edges have some data/attributes, otherwise, the dictionary will be empty.

To make your code a bit more robust to this situation, you can use `.get` method:

```py
# note that this will return None for edges without data
edge_origins = [e[2].get("attr_dict", {}).get("Node1_reference") for e in g.edges(data=True)]
```

Here's a reproducible example:

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.path_graph(3)
G.add_edge(2, 3, weight=5)
print([e[2].get("weight") for e in G.edges(data=True)])
# [None, None, 5]
```